# How to stop minecraft eggs from spawning chicks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a build where I need a throwable item. While snowballs would be okay, they don't really look like what they're supposed to be. Eggs look more accurate.
The only problem is that they sometime spawn chicks, and I don't want that. Also, I don't have commands enabled, so any solutions that don't include commands or command blocks would be greatly appreciated!

**Is there any way of preventing the eggs from spawning chicks?**

Comment: Relevant: [How to turn cheats on or off](//gaming.stackexchange.com/q/277542)

Comment: Please remember folks that comments are not intended for extended discussions.

Comment: I don't see how this question is unclear. It's clearly asking how to prevent eggs from spawning chickens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without commands you can't do this. Short of making a system to kill all the chickens it spawns, throwing eggs will make chickens. As a result, you can either do one of 2 things:

- Use snowballs, you could always use a texture pack to re-texture them to look like acorns and make players download it before playing your map. In addition you could retexture other things in your map making it look better.
- Use commands, turn them on (just google how, there are various answers on arcade SE and also in general on the internet) and then set up a command block repeatedly killing all baby chickens (I'm not an expert in commands so I'm not too sure how the command would work, so I'll refrain from suggesting it)

Comment: Thank you for actually getting to the point. I know I can turn on commands by turning to LAN, and I know the command I'd have to use, but do you know how to turn a LAN world back into a normal world?